# Помогите организовать SQL-запрос

Tags: mysql, php, sql

У меня есть такая таблица:

```
params_detalis_users_xref  
id  
id_user     
id_param    
value_ot    
value_do
```

Т.е. у меня количество параметров динамично и регулируется в админке. И есть также поиск по этим параметрам. Пример забитых данных:
[image]
Мне нужно проверить так, чтобы по обоим параметрам проверялось одновременно. Я немного ступил и сделал такой запрос:

```
SELECT id_user FROM params_detalis_users_xref WHERE (id_param='1' and value_ot<=200 and value_do>=297) AND (id_param='2' and value_ot<=300 and value_do>=320)
```

Такой запрос мне ничего не возвращает, т.к. я одновременно проверяю парметр `id_param`, который не может быть равным нескольким значениям. Но если я заменю `AND` на `OR`, то на первый взгляд будет всё работать, но если один из параметров не совпадёт, то он всёравно мне вернёт 34го юзера, хотя один из параметров поиска не подходит. Была такая мысль: сравнивать общее количество параметров, с количеством  возвращённых одинаковых `id` юзера. Но это придётся делать запрос на общее количество параметров каждый раз, когда встречается новый `id_user`, а я хочу как можно меньше запросов. Прошу помощи у более опытных, пожалуйста:) Прошу прощения, если что-то не понятно написал, целый день работаю, уже плохо формулирую мысли:) Пожалуйста, если что-то не понятно, уточните.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы же знаете количество проверяемых параметров, когда генерируете запрос? Напишите OR и сравнивайте количество полученных строк с этим количеством. Видимо, ещё понадобится group by, так как подходящих пользователей может быть несколько:

```
SELECT id_user
FROM params_detalis_users_xref 
WHERE (id_param='1' and value_ot<=200 and value_do>=297) OR 
      (id_param='2' and value_ot<=300 and value_do>=320)
GROUP BY id_user
HAVING count(id_param)=2
```

Comment: Спасибо, кол-во параметров я могу подсчитать во время цикла, генерирующего запрос, спасибо большое!!! Но есть один нюанс,дело в том, что пользователь может не заполнить какой-нибудь из параметров, и в БД кол-во параметров у этого юзера не будет равно искомым. Это можно как-то в запросе проверить?

Comment: Допустим, параметров 3 (вы это тоже должны знать без запроса к базе), пользователь ввёл 1-й и 3-й. Всё будет нормально:

SELECT id_user
FROM params_detalis_users_xref 
WHERE (id_param='1' and value_ot<=200 and value_do>=297) OR 
      (id_param='3' and value_ot<=300 and value_do>=320)
GROUP BY id_user
HAVING count(id_param)=2

Comment: Нет, если пользователь ввёл 3, а у искомого юзера заполнено только 2, то можно как-то не учитывать 3-й параметр? Или лучше сделать, чтобы по умолчанию у искомых пользователей были забиты все параметры, независимо вводил ли их он или нет? Это впринципи не сложно, просто добавит сложности, в случаи когда в админке будет добавлятся какой-нибудь параметр, прийдётся всем пользователям добавить его.

Comment: Как-то странно это всё выглядит... Я думал, переменное количество параметров в таблице потому, что к разным пользователям применимы разные критерии

Так получается, что если для пользователя в таблице не было задано ни одного параметра (сейчас такое как бы не возможно, но если бы), то он должен выдаваться при любой фильтрации?

Comment: Да, действительно. Поэтому решил, чтобы у каждого пользователя были параметры эти и во всех полях по 0, если он не указывал. Спасибо, буду использовать Ваш запрос.

Comment: Да, это выглядит более естественно

Comment: а ещё вопрос: информацию о пользователь доставать ещё одним запросом? или в этом же запросе LEFT JOINом, что лучше по нагрузке на mysql?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так, но не уверен насчет правильности конструкций.. Поправьте меня.

```
SELECT `id_user`,`value_ot`,`value_do` FROM `params_detalis_users_xref ` WHERE `id_param` IN (1,2) GROUP BY `id_user` HAVING `value_ot`<=300 AND `value_do`>=320
```

Answer (score 0):

Сделай 1 запрос по id_param='1' и если получишь данные то гуд, нет делай второй запрос на id_param='2'

Comment: Нет, наоборот, если данные получаю, то проверяю следующий параметр. Мне нужно, чтобы совпадали все параметры, а не один из них. Просто параметров может быть и 10, 10 запросов получится... Или это не страшно?